# create the file or copy the file from docker container to host

Tags: linux, docker, copy-paste

Below is my code:

```
docker container run -it ubuntu /bin/bash -c "touch /root/test.txt"
```

What I wanted is this file to be created at my host. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Can you give a little more context around this question?  Docker containers run in isolated filesystems, and by default can't affect the host filesystem; but in this example you could directly run `touch /root/test.txt` without involving Docker at all.  If you can explain in a little more detail what you're trying to do and how Docker is involved (and what `docker run -v` options you're using) a better answer is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to mount a directory from the host in the container. Touch the .txt file in the location where you created the mount, inside the container.

This example will create on the docker host, in the working directory, the `test.txt` file:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/root/mout-from-host ubuntu /bin/bash -c "touch /root/mout-from-host/test.txt"
```

```
ls
test.txt <<--file on host, created by the container
```